# How to return to app from web service

Tags: ios, json, cordova

Edit:

I have a web service (written in PHP) to retrieve data and return the information using JSON, however I am unsure how to integrate this web service with my PhoneGap app. How do I do this?

---

Original question:

I have a basic app that uses a web service to retrieve data and displays the information using JSON, however I am unsure as to how to return to the app.

It is being coded in Dreamweaver using PhoneGap.

There is a form with a single input, the user selects "search" and it uses the web service to display the information.

However I cannot figure out how to go 'back' to the app as the loaded page is now on a different server.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I've tried to rephrase the question to make it clear that you're looking for advice in having a PhoneGap app consume a JSON web service.

Comment: Perfectly fine, does the job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [JQuery AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Here is an simple example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "your-web-service-url-here.php",

  //Optional data to send to the service.
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" } 

}).done(function( msg ) {

  //This is the JSON message received from the service.
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); 

});
```

Hope this helps.